# How to Make Jagged Borders Around Shape With Illustrator?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, shapes, borders

See the caption "Halloween Party" It is surrounded by a thick black shape or shall I say border.
The black shape looks as if it is outlined with jagged lines to resemble the blood and give the creepy feel. How is this jagged lines across the clack shape is achieved?
 [image]

Answer (score 2):

I believe it's *drawn*, much like the bats.. or the pumpkin....

Comment: The jagged lines is outlining the whole shape, not just the upper part of the shape, it just happened that the upper part is the most visible one!

Comment: My point was that there is *nothing* which is going to create this automatically for you. You have to draw it.

Comment: Can you suggest a method in your answer for creating one?

Comment: @AndrewMk I'm sorry. I don't understand. You want me to explain how to draw in my answer? There's nothing *automated* which is going to do this for you. You need to grab the Pen Tool or some other drawing tool and create the shapes you want the same way you'd create any other shape with the Pen Tool. As great as software can be, it won't draw for you. If it could, many would be out of a job.